# Как написать небольшое приложение на meteor.js и react.js без использования базы дынных?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, meteor

Я хочу понять как написать маленькое приложение в наподобии чата но без использования базы данных на `meteor.js` и `react.js`.

К сожалению в справочных примерах не рассмотрен такой случай поэтому вот примерно код как я его представляю, естественно он не работает как реактивный, и не `broadcasting` не срабатывает.

Вот пример кода, серверная часть:

```
export let ws = [{_id:'1', text:'test1'}, {_id:'2', text:'test2'}];
let ctr = 3;
Meteor.publish('ws', function wsPub() {
  let self = this;
  ws.forEach( (msg)=> {
    self.added( "msg", msg._id, msg.text );
  });
  self.ready();
  // return ws;
});
```

Клиентская часть:

```
import {ws} from '../api/model.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  addMsg(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('addMsg', this.refs.input.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {this.props.ws.map((item, i)=>{ 
           return(<span key={i._id}>{item.text}</span>); 
         })}
         <input type="text" ref="input" />
         <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick={this.addMsg.bind(this)}/>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
export default createContainer( () => {
  Meteor.subscribe('ws');
  return { ws: ws };
}, App);
```

Что я делаю не так и как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2pgKY376xI
То что вам нужно. В комментариях найдёте фиксы того, что уже не работает (так как видео слегка устаревшее), но идея вам будет ясна.